# Generating an unique ID from two values

Tags: algorithm, haskell, numbers

<s>What would be an idiomatic way of generating an unique number (say, a 64bit unsigned int) from two values, in such a way that the input values (also numbers of the same type) could be regenerated from the number, as a Haskell function?</s>

On C/C++ I would probably use something like

```
result = (((value1) << BITS) + ((value2) & ((1 << BITS) - 1)))
```

and, accordingly,

```
value1 = (result >> BITS)
```

and

```
value2 = (result & ((1 << BITS) - 1))
```

for regenerating the values, but I don't think I should be trying to use bitwise operations in Haskell.

After consideration, I simply abandoned the idea of using bitwise operations and resorted to [Cantor's pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function):

```
pair :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
pair x y = (1 / 2) * (x + y) * (x + y + 1) + y

unpair :: (RealFrac a, Floating a) => a -> (a, a)
unpair z = (x, y) where
    q = (-1 / 2) + sqrt (1 / 4 + 2 * z)
    j = fromInteger (truncate q)
    y = z - ((1 / 2) * j * (j + 1))
    x = j - y
```

This is probably the way I should have thought from the beginning. Thank you all very much for helping me to better understand bit operations on Haskell, though.

Comment: If this is the "right" way to mix the values, then do the same in Haskell.

Comment: Given the two very different answers: Do you want to store Haskell values (like, say, `Maybe Bool`) in the number, or do are the values you talk about already numbers?

Comment: The values are already numbers.

Comment: Ok, then that is a very different issue... deleting my answer.

Comment: @NoeticJun: The cantor pairing function is substantially slower than merging two n-bit values into a single 2n-bit value.

Comment: What is "substantial" slowdown in this case? A factor of 2, 3, more? Anyway, this is not a performance-critical case, so, unless the slowdown is truly massive (which it shouldn't be), that's not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the exact same way in Haskell. Bitwise operations can be found in [`Data.Bits`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Bits.html) and unsigned, fixed-sized integer types in [`Data.Word`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Word.html). For example:

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

combine :: Word32 -> Word32 -> Word64
combine a b = (fromIntegral a `shiftL` 32) + fromIntegral b

separate :: Word64 -> (Word32, Word32)
separate w = (fromIntegral $ w `shiftR` 32, fromIntegral $ w .&. 0xffff)
```

The thing that might trip you up compared to C is that Haskell never converts between different numeric types implicitly, so you need to use `fromIntegral` to convert between e.g. 32bit and 64bit unsigned integers.

Comment: One of the cases where I like the C operators better - I always alias `shiftL` to `(<<)` and `shiftR` to `(>>)`.

Comment: The Op asked for “Haskell values”, not just numbers – I guess that needs to be clarified here...

Comment: The "values" are always ordinary numbers. Clarified in OP.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe The problem with that is when `(>>)` conflicts with `Prelude.(>>)`.  Since they aren't already used, I would recommend `(>>>)` and `(<<<)`.

Comment: `(>>>)` and `(<<<)` are defined in `Control.Arrow` though. :)  Maybe `(.<<.)` and `(.>>.)` to follow the same convention as bitwise and `(.&.)` and bitwise or `(.|.)`.

Comment: @bheklilr Hm, true - I never realized that! What @shang suggests sounds like a good compromise! `x .<<. 32` doesn't seem too bad to me.